# WPF Toolkit - Verify upgrade?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I have downloaded the latest version of the `WPF Toolkit` and have changed my existing reference from one DLL version to another within Visual Studio. Is this all I need to do to make sure that I'm using the latest `WPF datagrids` throughout my WPF application? I haven't changed any of the `XAML calls` since I believe it uses the exact same headers.

Changing the reference should ensure that I will be using the datagrids, right?

Comment: You do realize that [.NET 4 added support for DataGrid](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html) without using the toolkit - correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use in your `XAML` a `DataGrid` from `WPF Toolkit`, and you change a reference inside your project to the newest, just downloaded, version of `WPF Toolkit`, the answer is, yes, you use the latest version of `DataGrid`.

If it still compiles, you done.